# VMware Workstation guests NAT adapters always got the same IP address

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, nat, vmware-workstation

I'm on Windows and created three Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop virtual machines using VMware Workstation. This is my NAT and custom host-only network configuration.

[image]

This is my guest VM's network adapters. As you can see, the three VMs each has a NAT adapter as well as a host-only adapter.

[image]

I've set static IPs for the host-only adapters and for the NAT adapter I use DHCP. The netplan configuration is:

```
horton@c1master1:~$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
[sudo] password for horton:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: yes
    ens38:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.100/24]
horton@c1master1:~$
```

The problem is that the DHCP always assign the same IP addresses. As you can see in below image, the network interface cards have different MAC addresses.

[image]

Why this happen and how can I fix this? I know I can use `dhclient -r` and `dhclient` to get a new IP address and I confirmed this really works. But every time I shut the VMs down and restart them, they always get the same IP address.

Comment: `dhclient` essentialy requests for a dynamic IP from the DHCP server, i think when the server boots the system does not request for the IP and running the `dhclient` grabs an available IP from the pool, i observed my VM is also doing the same. I added `dhclient` to run at every boot to overcome this.